# Try to bold part of modal message bootstrap

Tags: javascript, smarty, bootstrap-modal

I use smarty class and bootstrap, and have this html tag:

```
`<a class="close" href="#" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete {$item.name} item? " ></a`>
```

Where {$item.name} is item name,from database.

For modal window,using this Js code:

```
     <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-confirm]').click(function(ev) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var cat = document.getElementById("catname").value;
        if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
            $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="dataConfirmLabel">Please Confirm</h3></div><div class="modal-body"></div><b></b><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button><a class="btn btn-danger" id="dataConfirmOK">Delete</a></div></div></div></div>');
        } 
        $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
        $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
        $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

All is fine,modal working ,text that I add in data-confirm in  tag shows and I get message like this :

Are you sure you want to delete Car item?

and,I try to be like this:

Are you sure you want to delete **Car** item?

I try with  tags in data-confirmation,don't work,also try to made vairable var and show directly in js code,no result..

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 0):

*Why don't you use a span and replace the content inside the  tag by this span.*

Something like this:

```
<span id="delConfirmLabel" href=# > Are you sure you want to delete 
<b> {$item.name} </b> item?</span>
```

now, replace the attribute **"data-confirm"** with **delConfirmLabel**'s content.